# How to achieve multithreading on Mongo Async Java Driver?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, performance, mongodb

I am trying to achieve a high throughput of Inserts/Second on a Spring application (without Spring data). I try to insert a million documents with the following code:

```
Address address = new Address();
address.setStreet1("");
address.setStreet2("");
address.setZipCode("");
address.setId(1234);
StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
stopWatch.start();
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i++).limit(1000000).parallel().
          forEach(i -> addressRepository.insert(address);
stopWatch.stop();
```

And the repository code as follows:

```
public void insert(Address address) {
       Document address = new Document("_id", address.getId()).
                         append("zip_code", address.getZipCode).
                         append("street_1", address.getStreet1()).
                         append("street_2", address.getStreet2());

      db.getCollection("address").insertOne(address, (Void result, Throwable t)
                                      -> System.out.println("Inserted"));
}
```

The maximum number of writes I could muster was around 4k/second. Is there any way to do this in a multithreaded way to get much higher writes per second?

My Spring bean configuration for MongoClient is:

```
 @Bean
 public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of direct async driver usage
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/tree/master/driver-async
and api doesn't look fine... I think it's not ready up to now.
PS: vert.x has true async mongo driver that works good (0% cpu during stress testing)

**updated**

Next Spring Data release will have reactive capabilities: ReactiveCrudRepository, ReactiveMongoTemplate, and so on. Cassandra and Redis are also in support list. Look for details [here](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/28/going-reactive-with-spring-data)

Comment: Don't create more answers - edit new information into your current answers: "Spring is going on a reactive way, we need to wait a little time https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/28/going-reactive-with-spring-data"

Answer (score 0):

I think that before trying multithreading you could check MongoDB bulk operations API (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) which is available in MongoDB Java Driver (BulkWriteOperation class).

Check: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/#bulk-operations:b8bcd3c4cba9ac16433f82561ee44461